# Returning a value from a bit complex javascript function back to silverlight user control

Tags: javascript, jquery, silverlight, callback, deferred

I have a silverlight user control where I have a textbox and a button. There can be multiple of these user controls within this silverlight page.

When button is clicked, I want to fire up a javascript function which calls jquery popup to open another page within same application via iframe. In that page, user does a search and data needs to be passed all the way down to silverlight user control and textbox needs to be filled with that.

Using HtmlPage Invoke method within silverlight I am able to call javascript function.
Within this javascript I am able to call jquery mobile popup as well. However, I am unable to return search word from that function down. Below function returns empty string immediately. I have used setTimeout and defer method but still no success.
In the popup window, when user is finished searching for word and closes the window, that popup function calls a parent function called setSearchWord(). This function is in this page which sets searchWord variable.

```
var searchWord = '';

function calljquerymobilePopUp(){
$("$popupWin").popup('open'); 
  //what should I do here such that I can make sure 'searchWord' 
  //variable is not empty and return it to silverlight user control.
   return searchWord;
}

function setSearchWord(val){
  searchWord = val;     
  // I always get this value but its always too late. 
  // In silverlight user control, I end up getting empty string
  console.log(searchWord);

  $("$popupWin").popup('close'); 
}
```

Comment: I think one issue I found is jquery mobile popup window is itself async method. So even though popup window is open, the rest of the function continue to execute. I will have to see if I can make this popup into a modal window and block further processing of the function until this window is closed.

Comment: It is important to know where the main page and the popup page are served from - with particular regard to their domains. This determines the application architecture. Also, you say "user does a search" but it's not clear exactly what is searched or where the search is carried out - client-side or server-side? Also it's not clear what the search result(s) is/are?

Comment: it is a basic search page done in .net. The resultant id is passed on to parent page function which is "setSearchWord". This all works, only thing is since the popup form is asynchronous, by the time search result is back and set, the function is already executed. I need some help on preventing function return unless the variable 'searchWord' is determined to be not empty.

Comment: Just to put it in different perspective, if I have a confirm box instead of popup dialog, the calling function wait for confirm box to finish execution and then executes remainder of the function. I just need similar functionality using jquery mobile popup box.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the API documentation for the jQuery mobile popup you are using.

Comment: http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/

Comment: I guess it depends on exactly how and where `setSearchWord` is called but I can't see that code.

Comment: I have shown the jquery function that calls setSearchWord function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('tap', '.btnSelectWord', function(){
        if( typeof parent.setSearchWord === 'function'){
            parent.setSearchWord(selectedPointId)
        }else if (typeof window.opener.setSearchWord == 'function'){
            window.opener.setSearchWord(selectedPointId);
        }
        else {
            console.log('No function')
            alert('No callback in parent')
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Bobsov, I can give you a possible way ahead but no better than that I'm afraid :

As it can't return a value directly, `openPopUp` needs to return a Promise, which will yield the required value when resolved. For javascript/jQuery, this is quite trivial, though it does involve global vars/functions due to your page/iFrame archtecture.

The code will be something like this (in the global namespace) :

```
var searchDfrd;

function openPopUp() {
    $("$popupWin").popup('open');
    searchDfrd = $.Deferred().done(function(val) {
        console.log(val);
    });
    return searchDfrd.promise();
}

function setSearchWord(val) {
    searchDfrd.resolve(val);
    $("$popupWin").popup('close');
}
```

Now comes the problem ... `openPopUp()` returns not to javascript but to Silverlight, from where it was called with `HtmlPage.Invoke`.

Without any great knowledge of Silverlight, I feel pretty confident in saying that Silverlight can't handle a jQuery Promise directly (it's not a javascript environment). The Promise will need to undergo some sort of translation.

After a bit of research, I hit on something called [SilverQuery](http://code.google.com/p/silverquery/), which "combines the power and expressiveness of jQuery with the productivity of .NET via a managed code bridge b/t the Silverlight runtime and the jQuery JavaScript library."

Unfortunately, I can't take this any further as I can't run tests on this computer and can't find evidence that Silverquery will bridge jQuery's Deferreds/Promises. These may well have been introduced after SilverQuery was written (the SilverQuery download is dated Sept 2009, when jQuery was at about 1.3 or 1.4 IIRC and didn't yet include the $.Deferred API).

Maybe someone else knows if SilverQuery is viable or, even better, of a simpler approach.

Comment: This is awesome help you provided. I am so grateful for that. This gives me ammunition to look at it in a whole different dimension. I will look into SilverQuery and see if there is possible solution here.

Answer (score 0):

JS popup functions are all async. They won't wait. There's really no way to make JS wait for popup window to be closed.

Now you can achieve the same result another way. I assume you want to block the thread because you do not want to let user do anything on the parent page? Why don't you disable everything on the parent page until the popup window is closed? You can create a floating DIV over the entire page right below the popup that will intercept all mouse events and do nothing.

Comment: Actually, the popup box is big enough not to allow user access to parent page. The problem is I would like to function call to wait for popup box to close and then continue with rest of the code execution. Instead, it just continues to execute. Silverlight user control gets null value immediately even if I put 20 seconds delay. For some reason, it does not like to even get delay by 20 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to give 'Pat' to myself for solving this issue. What I did was - I called same process above to launch popup box, but when setSearchWord function, the one called within popupbox to set id, I created a method in silverlight managed code that is exposed to javascript and calling that method where I am passing variable and setting the silverlight textbox.

Hope this makes sense. Basically, I created another method within managed code and exposed it to javascript by decorating it with [ScriptableMember]. This allowed me to call this method from javascript. Problem solved!!

Thank you Beetroot and Omar for your comments and suggestions which kept me going.